# ArrayList.size() returning incorrect value

Tags: java, arraylist, size

I have a strange error which I can not get my head around where the .size() method does not appear to return the correct value.

This first bit of code creates the ArrayList.

```
public void createResultList(String query) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList();

    try {
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();

        for(int i = 0; i < meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            data.add(i, new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        int x = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            for(int y = 0; y < meta.getColumnCount(); y++) {
                data.get(x).add(rs.getString(y + 1));
            }
            x++;
        }


    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    ResultTable result = new ResultTable(data);
    JTable table = new JTable(result);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollpane);
    refresh();
}
```

This is my TableModel class which is used to create the table when it's passed to it.

```
public class ResultTable extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data;

    public ResultTable(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() { 
        return data.get(0).size(); 
    }

    public int getRowCount() { 
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
        return data.get(row).get(col);
    }
}
```

Now the the problem is in the ResultTable class, now for a select query returning one row with 12 columns, the first data.get(0).size() call correctly returns 12, but the 2nd data.size() call incorrectly returns 12 also instead of 1, this is causing out of bounds errors, can anyone please explain this seemingly paradoxical result?

Comment: Why do you think that the `data.size()` should return `1`? You have added the same number of `ArrayList` as the number of strings to the inner `ArrayList`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you should've found easily when you debug your code...

```
public void createResultList(String query) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList();
```

data is an ArrayList of ArrayLists

```
    try {
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

A query returning 1 row of 12 columns

```
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        for(int i = 0; i < meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
```

For each column in your recordset, being 12, you add an empty ArrayList in data

```
            data.add(i, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
```

resulting in data being an ArrayList of 12 empty Arraylists
This already explains why data.size() == 12

```
        int x = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
```

for each record in your recordset, being 1

```
            for(int y = 0; y < meta.getColumnCount(); y++) {
```

for each column in your recordset, being 12, you add a string to the ArrayList with the same index as the recordset

```
                data.get(x).add(rs.getString(y + 1));
            }
```

The first ArrayList in data (data.get(0)) will have 12 Strings
All other ArrayLists in data (data.get(x) where x > 0) will remain empty

```
            x++;
        }
```

Resulting in data being an ArrayList of 12 ArrayLists
of which only the first ArrayList has 12 Strings and the others are empty

```
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    ResultTable result = new ResultTable(data);
    JTable table = new JTable(result);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollpane);
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks, I think I was so focused on the part of the code where the strings are added that I forgot about the preceding part where the ArrayLists were added.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `data` list, you create a sublist to hold the data for each column.

If that is what you want to do, you should add data from each column of the result set to the list that corresponds to it:

```
    while(rs.next()) {
        for(int y = 0; y < meta.getColumnCount(); y++) {
            data.get(y).add(rs.getString(y + 1));
        }
    }
```